# Is there an override func to allow a webview displaying a pdf to enable pinch & zoom?

Tags: xcode10, swift4.2

I am able to load the pdf successfully, however, it will not pinch and zoom when loaded onto my iPhone XS Max.

I have looked around for a while now and most of the previously answered questions regarding this say to select 'scale to fit' however that is not an option in my Xcode

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class constantsinphysicsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "constants", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)
        {
            let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf)
            webView.load(req as URLRequest)


        }

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Disposes of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: the bottom func touchesBegan is for allowing for a keypad to go away when the screen is touched anywhere else.   I can remove this from this script if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the overall view's class I just left it as UIView

Then I drag and dropped "WebKit View" into the view itself and resized it to the desired size.

Initially, I thought that I had to put layout constraints on it by setting the vertical space to the top label, which vertical spacing set to the Top Safe Space.  However, when I tried to put layout constraints on the dragged and dropped WebKit View it messed up the pdf inside.  So just set the layout constraints for the top label to the top safe space, and the bottom button to the bottom safe space and left the WebKit View alone (after I put my personal sizing on it) and loaded to my iPhone and it worked... AND it has pinch and zoom enabled!  yyyeessss!!!

I will post some pictures of the process tomorrow.

I am still willing to take comments.